# How to use blade fuse in DC circuit as protection?

Tags: circuit-analysis, protection, fuses, circuit-protection

While trying to add a protection to my buck converter circuit I came across Blade Fuses, which are faster at breaking compared to glass cartridge from what I saw. The question is, **how is such a fuse supposed to be wired in a *DC* circuit?** Yes it has only 2 terminals and it's non-polarized (from what I know) so it could just be just put in series with VCC in a circuit like in the diagram below, *(Rm1 is a dummy load)*

[image]

[But then why does its PCB mount holder have 4 pins?](https://ro.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Keystone-Electronics/3568?qs=fP5bVVCrK%2Fd7nbA%2FPpwnKw%3D%3D) **Why 4** and not 2? Or are the first 2 and last 2 the same but in pairs? [**This fuse** I was planning on using](https://ro.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Littelfuse/0997020.WXN?qs=qI%252BDxnNls188g1lAAM3PWQ%3D%3D) **(which is rated for 58VDC, 20A)** and is compatible with the holder below has just the basic 2 terminals
[image]

If indeed they're the same pins but in pairs, **then the correct schematic (using the symbol for the holder linked above) is this**?
[image]

Comment: just a first thought ... blade fuses require more force to extract ... you wouldn't want the fuse holder to fail due to inadequate anchoring ... also, blade fuses are available in high current versions, so the holder has to be able to pass the current

Comment: @jsotola the fuse mentioned in the link above is rated for **20A at 58V DC**, which is a very small amount. So... They're harder to extract, which would mean a risk of damaging the PCB itself when extracting? What do you mean by "anchoring"? Also, **the fuse holder itself can handle 30A**, which should be enough until the fuse itself breaks

Comment: If you could see the contacts end-on they look a bit like a letter M, so for secure mounting the outside two verticals are both soldered into the PCB.

Comment: @Finbarr What do you mean by *"outside two verticals"*? There's on pair on each side. You think one of the terminals is for the fuse itself and the other is for secure mounting?

Comment: They're both for electrical connection AND secure mounting

Comment: _”then the correct schematic is this?”_ There is an IEC standard symbol for a fuse. Use that instead of a block with four ports.

Comment: @Finbarr Ok, then each lead of the fuse gets split into a pair, right? So the way it is connected in the third image is correct? Also, if you're sure this is right, post it as an answer

Comment: @winny The standard symbol was used indeed in the first schematic, but the second is intended to be represented using the symbol from mouser for this holder

Comment: Are you using library loader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how is such a fuse supposed to be wired in a DC circuit?

As your schematic shows, but you'll need to have two pins on each side if you use that holder.

> But then why does its PCB mount holder have 4 pins?

Because it takes two men and a boy* to pull the fuse out of the holder, and it would be *really embarrassing* if you pulled the holder off of the board, instead.

Or, more formally: it's there for mechanical strength.  It is typical when you have something attached to a board that's going to need a lot of support for it to have through-hole features that are designed to support it mechanically, as well as having electrical connections.

In fact, it is pretty common for connectors and controls (i.e. potentiometers) to have through-hole features that don't participate electrically, yet still get soldered onto the board, or that snap into an unplated hole.

---

* American colloquialism** for "lots of force".  Sorry.  Not sorry.

** Possibly also the entire rest of the world -- it's a pretty obvious image.

Comment: By "you'll need to have two pins on each side if you use that holder", you mean [this kind]( https://ro.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Littelfuse/0997020.WXN?qs=qI%252BDxnNls188g1lAAM3PWQ%3D%3D ) of fuse with only 2 leads won't work, and that it must have 4 leads? **That's all I'm asking**. If the linked fuse will work with the connector

Comment: @Mito You're asking lots of things in the question, but whether the linked fuse will work with the connector is not one of them.

Comment: If you want to add to your question, then edit **the actual question** with your additional query.

Answer (score 2):

> *The question is, how is such a fuse supposed to be wired in a DC
> circuit?*

They need to be used with a holder....

> *But then why does its PCB mount holder have 4 pins? Why 4 and not 2?
> Or are the first 2 and last 2 the same but in pairs?*

The fuse holder has 4 terminals. The two at end are electrically connected via the fuse clip spring metal. You can almost see it in the data sheet for the part: -

[image]

Not only do they provide a better electrical connection (and some pins are bent in a way to make soldering easier) but, mechanically it improves things.

Comment: Ok, so the last schematic using the symbol from mouser is correct, right? The 4 terminals are there only for secure mounting and better electrical connection

Comment: "They need to be used with a holder....", and this one is the one required? Asking for clarification since it will be used in the final buck converter and the components on the PCB must be compatible

Comment: I can only answer the questions you raised. I cannot say it is compatible. You said it was compatible in your question.